# Update position of div while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

For another stack question I have tried to write a short script. It should track the position of a div `.list_item` while scrolling and apply the `.offset().top` to another div.

To test if the function is fired I have written a `console.log` inside my code, which was never seen again. *Why does my function do not fire while scrolling?*

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // fire function everytime the window is scrolled
    $(window).scroll(function(){

    // set element to relate to
    var list_items = $('div.list_item');

    // get each position
    list_items.each(function() {
      // store offset().top inside var
      var list_item_position = $(this).offset().top;
      // select previous dropdown_list item
      $(this).prev().find('ul.dropdown_list').css({
        // apply offset top
        top: list_item_position + "px"
      });
    });

    // write to console to track changes
    console.log('positions updated');

  }); // .scroll

}); // document.ready
```

Suggestions appreciated!

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/marianrick/w030L59t/2/)

Comment: Hey marian, your scroll listener is being applied to the document, to track the scroll inside your wrapper you should use : $('#wrapper').scroll(function(){}); instead of window.  It's what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Why don't you try to use CSS instead of doing this by JQuery?

Comment: try `$('html, body').scroll` instead.

Comment: Scroll event happen only if you have scrollbar and you scroll.

Comment: @CarlosDelgado super genius and simple, thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Carlos Delgado in the comments, `$(window).scroll` tracks, if the windows is being scrolled, while setting the first line to `$('#wrapper').scroll` tracks, if the `#wrapper` is being scrolled, which works perfect.

Thanks for pointing this out and the other helpful comments!